# CATCH errors in trigger

Tags: sql-server

I have this insert trigger setup

```
DECLARE @clid varchar(80)
SET @clid = (SELECT clid FROM inserted)
EXEC Track.dbo.InsertCall @clid
```

For some reason this sometimes fails, which stops the insert on the table the trigger is declared on.

I need the insert to happen, even if the trigger fails for any reason.

I tried this:

```
DECLARE @clid varchar(80)
SET @clid = (SELECT clid FROM inserted)

BEGIN TRY
EXEC Track.dbo.InsertCall @clid
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
INSERT INTO errors(errornumber,errorseverity,errorstate,errorprocedure,errorline,errormessage) VALUES (ERROR_NUMBER(),ERROR_SEVERITY(), ERROR_STATE(), ERROR_PROCEDURE(), ERROR_LINE(), ERROR_MESSAGE())
END CATCH
```

The insert still fails, and nothing is logged to my errors table.

If I disable the trigger everything works fine again.

Thanks

Comment: you cannot do a select from inserted and store it in one variable because inserted can contain more than one row.

Comment: show the code on insertcall

Comment: You'll need to dig deeper and find out what, exactly, is failing and how. T-SQL is *not* a happy language for error handling, and (as you've discovered) `TRY-CATCH` doesn't mean you can always proceed. What you're literally asking for (a statement that never fails even if the trigger fails for *any* reason) is probably impossible, since some errors always terminate the statement/batch. See [the articles by Erland Sommarskog](http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html#classification) for the gory details. You'll need to set your sights a little lower than that.